# I am getting this following errror in my website

Tags: asp.net

Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

Comment: Are you using FormsAuthentication and is your site on a single server

Comment: Is it just in your Dev environment? Sometimes you are required to restart the VS virtual server to remove this error in Dev.

Comment: Have you read this **http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tom/archive/2008/03/14/validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed-error.aspx ??**

Answer (score 0):

Are you load balancing your site across multiple servers?

http://forums.iis.net/p/1148193/1864450.aspx

> The machineKey value has to be the same on all machines in a webfarm.
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998288.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this in web.config:

```
<pages enableEventValidation="false" viewStateEncryptionMode="Never">
```